# Flutter populate form with async data

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to fetch a user and then populate a form with its data but I can't seem to do this without breaking rules or having the form and the state go out of sync with each other.

Basically I have a `FutureBuilder` which fetches the user and sets `initialValue` of both `TextFormField` widgets using the data, however its the `setState` here that's disallowed and I'm not sure how to work around it.

I tried fetching the user in `initState` instead but that doesn't work since the data is async so the `initialValue` properties never gets the data.

Been looking through numerous sources on this but haven't found what I'm looking for,[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46481638/how-to-properly-pre-fill-flutter-form-field) comes close but seems to require the use of a `TextEditingController` which I would really like to avoid if possible.

What's the correct way to do this?

```
Map form = {};

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder(
      future: locator<AppAuth>().currentUser(),
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<FirebaseUser> user) {

        if (user.hasData) {

          setState(() {
            form['displayName'] = user.data.displayName;
            form['email'] = user.data.email;
          });

          return Scaffold(
            body: Form(
              key: _formKey,
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  TextFormField(
                    initialValue: form['displayName'],
                    onChanged: (v) {
                      setState(() {
                        form['displayName'] = v;
                      });
                    }
                  ),
                  TextFormField(
                    initialValue: form['email'],
                    onChanged: (v) {
                      setState(() {
                        form['email'] = v;
                      });
                    }
                  )
                ],
                / ... more code ... /
```

Comment: why do you need setState to be called inside FutureBuilder?

Comment: @pskink To access the form values once the form is submitted. I think I've found a way to do this though using `AsyncMemoizer` and `TextEditingController`s however where there is no need to have the form value is the state anymore, thus solving the problem.

Comment: setState is used for rebuilding your StatefulWisget and this is not such a  case (you don't need to rebuild it)

Comment: @pskink Yeah exactly. That's why the solution I mentioned is perfect :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was multiple issues here but I've managed to solve it using `AsyncMemoizer` and `TextEditingController`:

```
final AsyncMemoizer _memoizer = AsyncMemoizer();
final dnController = new TextEditingController();

// Only fetch data once and set its text value
// Setting it here ensures that the value doesn't go back
// to the stored user value on every widget rebuild
Future<dynamic> getUser() {

  return this._memoizer.runOnce(() async {

    final user = await locator<AppAuth>().currentUser();

    dnController.text = user.displayName;

    return user;
  });
}

// Set it as the future
return FutureBuilder(
  future: getUser(),
  ...

TextFormField(controller: dnController)
```

I hope this helps someone else encountering the same issue(s).

Answer (score 2):

Take a try with this:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';

class FutureForm extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _FutureFormState createState() => _FutureFormState();
}

class _FutureFormState extends State<FutureForm> {
  TextEditingController emailController = TextEditingController(text: "");
  TextEditingController nameController = TextEditingController(text: "");

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Demo Future form"),
      ),
      body: buildBody(context),
    );
  }

  Widget buildBody(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder(
        future: getCurrentUser(),
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<User> snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            nameController.text = snapshot.data.displayName;
            emailController.text = snapshot.data.email;
          }
          return Form(
              child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              TextFormField(
                controller: nameController,
              ),
              TextFormField(
                controller: emailController,
              )
            ],
          ));
        });
  }

  Future<User> getCurrentUser() async {
    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 2));
    return User("Doan Thanh Duong", "doanthanhduong@xmail.com");
  }
}

class User {
  final String displayName;
  final String email;

  User(this.displayName, this.email);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried over a dozen combinations of approaches to populate an email `TextFormField`  with a pre-saved value retrieved asynchronously from [SecureStorage](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_secure_storage). And although I'm sure other approaches work in other contexts (I'm still quite new to the mobile/Flutter field), this is what finally worked for me.

[auth_card.dart]

```
class _AuthCardState extends State<AuthCard> {

  TextEditingController _formControllerEmail;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    Provider.of<Auth>(context, listen: false).getLoginEmail.then((value) {
      setState(() {
        if (value != null) {
          _formControllerEmail = TextEditingController(text: value);
        } else {
          _formControllerEmail = TextEditingController();
        }
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    _formControllerEmail.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return TextFormField(
      keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
      controller: _formControllerEmail,
    );
  }
}
```

[auth_provider.dart]

```
Future<String> get getLoginEmail async {
  final secureStorageStore = new FlutterSecureStorage();
  final storageKey = await secureStorageStore.read(key: 'userEmail');
  if (storageKey == null || storageKey.length == 0) {
    return null;
  } else {
    return storageKey;
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this !

```
TextEditingController _nameCtrl,emailCtrl;
String mName='',mEmail='';
Map form = {};

void initState() {
  super.initState();
  nameCtrl = TextEditingController(text:mName);
  emailCtrl = TextEditingController(text:mEmail);
}

void dispose() {
  nameCtrl.dispose();
  emailCtrl.dispose();
  super.dispose();
}
```

and assign value on getting

```
setState(() {
    mName = user.data.displayName;
    mEmail = user.data.email;
   });
```

Populate Column

```
children: <Widget>[
           TextField(
             controller: nameCtrl,
             onChanged: (v) {
             setState(() {
               form['displayName'] = v;
             });
            }
           ),
          TextField(
            controller: emailCtrl,
            onChanged: (v) {
            setState(() {
               form['email'] = v;
            });
           }
          )
        ],
```

Comment: Hi, this answer does not take the async nature into consideration.

Comment: Then don't use future builder and separate getting user method  and try the above code !!