# Flutter form population via GlobalKey<FormState>

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a large form in my flutter application that I want to either use for editing customer information or creating a new customer.

in order to do this I check for an existing customer entity and if present "Populate the form" with existing customer data.

I could go through each field and add `initialValue: if Customer != null .....`. but it seems like this should be doable at a larger scale via FormState in the Global Key.

**Question**:

> "Is it possible to populate form input fields via the
> GlobalKey"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to properly pre-fill flutter form field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46481638/how-to-properly-pre-fill-flutter-form-field)

Comment: @Benjamin I was hoping not to have to use initial value at input field level. I was hoping that there was a way to populate from an external object and map to the fields, opposite to the way GlobalKey<FormState> save() function stores form data in state.

Comment: Unfortunately, there's no good way. There are some good external packages for better forms but natively, your best bet is `initialValue`.

Comment: The external packages tend to take away the textField/validation boilerplate but don't solve the pre-pop issue. Thanks for the response anyway.

Comment: @Yonkee How would you expect this to work?

Comment: @ChristopherMoore I imagined there would be a way to populate an object into the Form State which could be mapped to the fields initalValue.

Comment: @Yonkee If you were to do that, you would lose type safety, which is almost certainly why this is not available. This functionality cannot be compared to the `save` method.

Comment: @ChristopherMoore Thats a fair point.